# How do sort operator works?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

(Here a is an array, asize is the size of array.)

My question is that can someone explain why sort requires 'a' and 'a + asize' in it and what it does with it?

[image: code snippet here]

Comment: Presumably, `a` is a pointer to the beginning of the array and `a + asize` would be the pointer to the past-end of the array (i.e. to the "imaginary" element that would exist immediately after the last real element of the array). As for the actual algorithm employed, this topic is way to broad for a simple StackOverflow post. It's probably some variant of quicksort (possibly introsort).

Comment: Looking at the tag `c++`, I would propose to read [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: Deja vu. The exactly same question with the exactly same picture was here a several hours ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is an array. In various contexts, when an array is referring to by just its name, it will *decay* into a pointer to its 1st element.

Adding `asize` to such a pointer will perform *pointer arithmetic* to advance the pointer by `asize` number of elements.

`std::sort()` takes 2 iterators as input, denoting a range of values `[start, end)`. Meaning it will loop through and sort the values including `start` up to, but not including, `end`.

Pointers to elements in an array are valid iterators.  So, a statement like `sort(a, a + asize)` is the same as `sort(&a[0], &a[asize])`.

Answer (score 0):

Credit: Branko Dimitrijevic

So the `a` is a pointer that points towards the beginning of the array and `a+asize` would be the pointer to the "imaginary" that exists immediately after the last real element of array.